# How do I determine basement wall stud height?

Tags: basement, framing

I'm building a non load bearing wall. Building on the floor and lifting in place. All the videos I've watched say measure from floor to ceiling in multiple places and take the lowest measurement and subtract 1/8 of an inch. On one end of the wall I measure 8'10 1/4 and the opposite end I measure 8'10 1/16.

Is there any reason I can't custom cut each stud to fit better? Or would I just cut them all 8'10 1/16 minus 1/8?  That would leave it tight on one end and loose on the other.

Comment: I would just take 8'10" as my measurement and shim the rest. It's a partition wall, don't spend time on something that doesn't matter. Little short is always easier to work with. Way better than trying to jam under the joist or worse yet, having to take it apart because it's too long.

Comment: @basement_diy Thanks. I'm new at this so your advice helps.

Answer (score 1):

If anything, throw another nail in there to make up for the strength loss. Don't torture yourself with unique cuts for each stud. Item 2 from [IRC R602.3](https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/IRC2021P2/chapter-6-wall-construction#IRC2021P2_Pt03_Ch06_SecR602.3) gives a few nail count plus size alternatives. With a 5/16" gap, I would prefer the longest nails, 10d box nails with a count of 3. The IRC specification could already account for *a* gap. Something like 1/8" sounds likely.

Taking tight fit, 3-10d box nails, and no drywall layer as the baseline strength, a 5/16" gap with 4-10d box nails gets the connection strength back to 92% of the baseline. If there's a layer of 1/2" drywall in there in addition to the 5/16" gap, 3-16d common nails gets the connection strength back to 73% of the baseline.

Table 1-1 from the AWC's [General Dowel Equations for Calculating Lateral Connection Values](https://awc.org/wp-content/uploads/2021/12/AWC-TR12-1510.pdf) has a "g" variable to account for the gap. With those equations plus dowel bearing strength from Chapter 12 of the AWC's [NDS](https://awc.org/publications/2024-nds/) (Table 12.3.3), you can compute the nail lateral strength with g = 0" versus g = 5/16". To account for a 1/2" drywall layer, you can take its bearing strength as zero and compute the strength with g = 1/2" + 5/16".

*No Drywall Pinched in the Connection*

For a 10d box nail in Spruce-Pine-Fir fit up tight (g = 0"), a single 10d box nail fails by bending twice, once in the top plate and once in the floor joist (mode IV). It has a strength of 80#. Fitting the top plate up with a 5/16" gap (g = 5/16") reduces the per-nail strength to 55#. For 3-10d box nails and tight fit, the connection strength is 3(80#) = 240#. Adding another nail, the 5/16" gap connection has nearly the same strength, 4(55#) = 220#.

*1/2" Drywall Pinched in the Connection*

No gap (g = 1/2") implies a per-fastener strength of 45#. Adding another 5/16" (g = 13/16") implies a per-fastener strength of 31#. The 1/2" drywall plus 5/16" gap case is interesting because the nail now only bends in the top plate (mode III<sub>m</sub>), unlike all of the other cases so far. With the 1/2" drywall plus 5/16" gap, 16d common nails get a strength of 58# per nail (back in mode IV again, with the nail bending twice).

(If anybody is trying to go through the General Dowel Equations document, the M<sub>s</sub> and M<sub>m</sub> in Table 1-1 are mistaken, where they should be M<sub>ds</sub> and M<sub>dm</sub>, respectively.)

Comment: Your first 2 sentences make sense. After that you lost me lol. I'm new at this so that's way over my head. Thanks for the response nonetheless.

Comment: Appreciate the depth of knowledge you’re sharing.

Comment: @Aloysius, I was about to say "don't worry about it, weirdo," when I realized that I have no intuition for nails with gaps. Then I felt pangs of conscience for a fire blocking detail around my basement's perimeter with drywall pinched between the top plate and ceiling joists. I just threw 3-16d common nails in each connections and called it good. The only spec for required strength that I know of is [IBC2021's 1607.16](https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/IBC2021P2/chapter-16-structural-design#IBC2021P2_Ch16_Sec1607.16). 5psf. For joists on 24" centers and 8' walls, that's 40# required strength.

Comment: @Aloysius, designing for just 40# would be a disaster, though, given all of the stuff that people hang from their walls. I wouldn't be surprised if the 3-10d box nails is conventional wisdom that has been grandfathered in. Ah, it's probably an exterior, wind loaded wall thing, where the interior walls get the same schedule. It would be awkward for people deciding what to hang where if they had extra complexity based on the wall's specifics.

Comment: Getting into the weeds, but would it be considered a gap if you had a top top plate (sic), slid a built wall in underneath (with its own top plate) and then used shims at every nail point? (The extra plate strategy often helps with raising a wall... I'd usually do the bottom plate but the gap at the top sounds easier to me.)

Comment: @Aloysius, assuming it's the exact same material as the upper and lower top plate materials, I'd still treat it as a gap. Looking at the mode IV drawing on the left from page 11 of https://awc.org/wp-content/uploads/2021/12/AWC-TR12-1510.pdf, imagine your shim installed between the two outer plies. The nail head is on the left (the "s" subscripts are for "side). There are three different scenarios at ultimate load: slip plane on the left only, slip plane on the right only, and slip plane at both sides. To maintain the same strength generally, you need the first scenario.

Comment: @Aloysius, to maintain the same strength under mode IV, you need one of the first two scenarios. In the third case, however, the pressure inside your shim transitions between the two directions shown in the picture. This implies a loss of mode IV strength. The actual strength is somewhere between, of course. I would also worry about the shim attaining its bearing strength before splitting or something. Shims tend not to have the surrounding material to restrain the wood from splitting.

Comment: @Aloysius, but the shims sound good for eliminating potential squeaks.